# How does JWT DefaultAuthenticateScheme work?

Tags: jwt

I am new to JWT and identity servers. Can someone please explain me this code, what these codes means, and how are they connected.

We add authentication here, we are saying that the DefaultAuthenticateScheme from asp.net core will be initialised as the scheme from jwt bearer. What is the difference, and how this things works.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x => {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = false;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
```

Comment: This is probably too broad for Stack Overflow. Would you explain what specific thing you did not understand, and how it relates to things that you do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very informative article in the official docs.

Check it out:
[Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

I hope this helps!